# Where to define static array related to an entity in symfony2 ?

Tags: arrays, symfony, static, twig

I have an array contains static data related to an entity **Product**:

```
public static $category = array(
    1 => 'animal.png',
    2 => 'blague.png',
    3 => 'devinette.png',
    4 => 'enfant.png',
    5 => 'h-f.png',
    6 => 'nationalite.png',
    7 => 'politique.png',
    8 => 'sport.png',
    9 => 'name',
    10 => 'travail.png',
    11 => 'vulgaire.png',
    12 => 'autre.png',
);
```

Where i should declare the array ?

And how i can accede to data from the Twig view ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `Product` entity passed to the Twig template? (in other words, is it passed as an argument with the `$this->render(...)` function?)

Comment: That what i acutely did, but i thought that there is an other method with twig ?

Comment: Yes, we can define constants with Twig (named [global variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html)). But I think that if your data is related to an entity it's logical to keep it inside the Entity.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if that's the best way but I used something similar to your code:

```
class Product
{
    protected static $category = array( 
        1 => 'animal.png',
        2 => 'blague.png',
        3 => 'devinette.png',
        // ...
        )
    );
}
```

Then you can add some functions in this class in order to get data from the array

```
    public function getCategoryImageFromIndex($a)
    {
        return self::$category[$a];
    }

    // if you have a getter getCategory() which returns the category of the Product
    public function getCategoryImage()
    {
        return self::$category[$this->getCategory()];
    }
```

Then you can call these functions from Twig:

```
{{ product.categoryImageFromIndex(1) }}
```

will display:

> animal.png

And

```
{{ product.categoryImage }}
```

will display the corresponding image from the category.

Comment: Hi @Haithem Rihane if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used a Twig extension function to access the static array.

For example, in my Order entity, I have something like this:

```
class Order
{
    const ORDER_STATUS_PENDING = 0;
    const ORDER_STATUS_AWAITING_PAYMENT = 1;
    const ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETE = 2;

    public static $ORDER_STATUS_DISPLAY = [
        self::ORDER_STATUS_PENDING => 'Pending',
        self::ORDER_STATUS_AWAITING_PAYMENT => 'Order placed',
        self::ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETE => 'Order completed',
    ];
```

then assuming you already have a registered [Twig_Extension class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html), create a new filter function:

```
public function displayOrderStatus($orderStatus)
{
    return Order::$ORDER_STATUS_DISPLAY[$orderStatus];
}
```

Finally, use the filter in your Twig template:

```
{{ order.orderStatus|displayOrderStatus }}
```